# How to exclude .svn folders from a ZIP archive?

Tags: svn, zip

I am working on a game (Quake 3) and use an SVN repository to store the code tree. The tree also contains game data (textures, models, etc). This must be put into a PK3 archive (a standard ZIP archive with a different extension). I use the ZIP utility in a simple script to create the PK3 archive.

My problem is that the game data is also versioned, and the folder containing the data is cluttered with all those '.svn' subfolders. Of course, ZIP includes these subfolders into the archive. They are not needed by the game. Is there a simple way to tell ZIP to exclude all '.svn' subfolders from the archive?

Comment: What tool are you using to create the `.PK3` archive? Perhaps that tool takes in an "ignored file extensions" argument, or a whitelist which would not contain any files in the `.svn` folder.

Comment: I use the standard Linux ZIP utility (and its GNU port under Windows). It has options to exclude files, but not directories AFAIK.

Answer (score 30):

```
zip -r output.zip inputdir -x "**/.svn**"
```

this will exclude everything starting with ".svn" in any subfolder

Comment: Could you explain that syntax? Why are the quotations needed?

Comment: quotations are needed to avoid shell expansion in the case you have some file or folder in the current path matching that pattern.

`-r` means to travel recursively the input path (inputdir) while double stars `**` means to match subfolders

Answer (score 6):

Instead of zipping the source tree directly, why not have your script export a copy of the source tree without the `.svn` directories? There's a tool for that: [svn export](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.export.html).

Comment: This is your only real answer.  However it is worth mentioning that in svn 1.7 the working copy changed - there is a single .svn directory at the top level of the repository rather than in every directory.  This may help (particularly if the textures are large and would take some time to export)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. It seems that the Debian VPS on which I have the repository runs SVN 1.6.12 from Collabnet. I will just have to upgrade to 1.7 or later and the '.svn' folders will be gone.

Comment: While you're waiting for that, `svn export` has existed since day one. So I'd really suggest you look into that. :-)

Comment: Not very helpful if part of your file system is on svn and another part contains data files excluded with `svn:ignore` :(

Answer (score 1):

I use Windows 7.
Baked into the OS you may `Right-Click` on any Folder and Select "`Send to`" and then Click "`Compressed (zipped) folder`".

There's a quirk I discovered where Windows will only compress the ***first*** folder with a dot (.) prefix.:
[Windows 7 “send to compressed (zip) folder” omits some folders whose name begins with a dot](https://superuser.com/questions/566123/windows-7-send-to-compressed-zip-folder-omits-some-folders-whose-name-begins)

This quirk (*or mysterious feature by design*) had me thinking...
What if I created an empty "*decoy*" dot (.) prefixed folder to Compress instead of my `.svn` folder?

Windows will not allow you to simply Right-Click and create a folder with a dot (.) prefix.
Using the CMD, I ran "`mkdir .skip_svn`" in the same directory the "`.svn`" folder was in.
I used this answer to figure that one out:
[How do I create a folder name that starts with a dot in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/331921/how-do-i-create-a-folder-name-that-starts-with-a-dot-in-windows-7/331924)

Compressing the directory keeps my little decoy "`.skip_svn`" folder ***but*** ignores the "`.svn`" folder.
No command-line interfaces **or** 3rd Party zipping software to install.
I realize this may not be ideal for many - it is by no means a definitive solution.
This was all I needed to make my backups **quicker** and they now take up a whole lot **less** space.